# Rotations for putting cones around sphere

Tags: opengl, glut

I want to put cones on the surface of a sphere like:

[image]

My attempt looks like:

```
// black sphere
initMaterials2();
drawSphere(0.8);

// red cones
int n = 6;
initMaterials();
double angleIncrement = 360/n;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(angleIncrement * i, 1, 0, 0);
        glRotatef(angleIncrement * j, 0, 0, 1);
        glTranslatef(0, 0.7, 0);
        drawCone(0.15, 0.6);
        glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see, a bunch of cones is clustered around one side... i think my computation for rotation is wrong ... how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks I need to change the order of the loop

```
int n = 3;
initMaterials();
double angleIncrement = 180/n;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(angleIncrement * i, 0, 1, 0);
    for (double angle = 0; angle < 360; angle += 45) {
        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(angle, 1, 0, 0);
        glTranslatef(0, 0.7, 0);
        drawCone(0.15, 0.6);
        glPopMatrix();
    }
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that you've found the solution yourself - please don't forget to accept your own answer asap.